# AWS t2 instance not accumulating CPUCreditBalance

Tags: amazon-web-services

The CPUCreditUsage(Count) and CPUCreditBalance(Count) in Cloudwatch graphs display nothing for t2.large instance which was deployed a couple of weeks ago.

Here is the graph:

[image]

Anybody have any insight on why instance is not accumulating CPUCredit?

Comment: It's not really clear from this graph whether it's not accumulating... it just not getting logged.  There should be a line at zero if your credit balance has flatlined.   Does it look the same if you only only display that one metric?  A few points on the left side of the graph, then nothing at all?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it isn't logging. There is no line at zero. Yes, a few data points on the left and nothing. I overlapped the graph with CPUUtilization to give usage estimate. That is well below Base performance.